# Where did mklink go, it is not recognized in Windows-11 Home?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, mklink

Following some hack for changing home directory name, you need to link the old directory to the new. Instruction said to use `mklink`. However, mklink is not recognized in `Windows-11 Home`.

Where did it go?

Has it been disabled or removed from the latest windows?

If not, where do I find it?

Comment: Thanks, I already resolved it using `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\<old>" -Target "C:\<new>"`. Just very weird that googling didn't return anything about that, while the MS [own page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) doesn't say anything about not being available on 10/11.

Comment: It's available in Command Prompt but not PowerShell (because it's an internal command of the former instead of a standalone executable; like "shell builtins").

Comment: @not2qubit - It is available but you were using PowerShell profile instead of the Command Prompt profile within Windows Terminal